# Where comes the error "DLL load failed while importing _greenlet"?

Tags: python, bots

i tried using the reddit video maker.

```
https://github.com/elebumm/RedditVideoMakerBot
```

After following the complete documentation and fixing some errors I´m getting an error I can`t fix.

Could you help me ?

```
https://pastebin.com/3e4H2rkR
```

Tried starting main.py

Did not start due to error I dont understand.

Comment: please dont post screenshot. copy and paste the error log instead

Comment: Problem might be solved by copying 6 dll and lib files here: C:*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Lib\site-packages\greenlet
and pasting them here: C:*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\greenlet

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Changed the format of the error.

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag That did not work - no changes in the error message :/

Comment: maybe try installing altest c++ executable from Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Comment: Installing Visual C++ worked for me on Windows